# Proper way to abstract Realm in Android apps

Tags: android, realm, abstraction

I'm trying out Realm.io in an Android app, though, to stay on the safe side, I would like to abstract the DB layer so that, in case of need, I can switch back to a standard SQLite based DB without rewriting most of the app.

I'm however finding it difficult to properly abstract Realm due to it's particular nature:

- When tied to a realm, RealmObjects are proxies so I cannot pass them around as they were POJOs.
- All Realm instances need to be properly opened and closed for every thread they are used in.

I've resorted to using the recent Realm.copyFromRealm() API instead of passing around RealmObjects tied to a Realm to get around these limitations but this way I think I'm loosing all the benefits of using realm (am I?).

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is possible to hide RealmResults as LiveData, see the [architectureComponentsExample](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/ddbebcb97a9b86ed458dece0e75143c60421e272/examples/architectureComponentsExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/arch) in Realm's repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to answer your first confusion.
There is really no need to pass around `RealmObject`s via intents, or in other terms no need of them being `parcelable` or `serializable`

What you should do is to pass around particular `primary id` or other parameter of that particular `RealmObject` via intent, so that you can query that RealmObject again in next activity.

For example suppose you pass primaryId while starting an activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_PRIMARY_ID, id);
```

Now inside `NextActivity` get id from intent and simply query `RealmObject`, i.e.,

```
int primaryId = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_PRIMARY_ID, -1);
YourRealmObject mObject = realm.where(YourRealmObject.class).equalTo("id", primaryId).findFirst();
```

See, you got your object in new activity, rather than worrying about passing the object around.

I don't know what particular problem you're getting into regarding opening and closing realm objects. Did you try Realm's `Transaction blocks`? You don't need to rely on opening and closing if you use that.

I hope this helps.

**Update**

Since you're looking for abstraction,

Just create a class like `DbUtils` and have a method there like `getYourObjectById` and then pass above id and retrieve your object in return. That makes it abstract in a way. You can then keep that class and method, and just change method content if you ever switch to another database solution.

Comment: That is a pattern I was trying to avoid: calling Realm methods inside non DB related logic. The main idea was to abstract this so that if tomorrow I have to switch to another kind of database I won't have to rewrite such code.

Comment: @MarcoRomano Then just create a class like `DbUtils` and have a method there like `getYourObjectById` and then pass above `id` and retrieve your object in `return`. Wouldn't that make it abstract ? You can then keep that class and method, and just change method content if you ever switch to another db

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoRomano Cool. I'm adding my last comment in the answer. Please accept the answer then so that others can get benefit for similar situation. Thanks.

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().` wait a second, doesn't that open a new Realm instance each time that you are supposed to close?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce As per my knowledge, You don't have to close it if you're just reading.

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo `For the UI thread the easiest way is to execute realm.close() in the onDestroy() method.` I don't think they'd specify that it ought to be closed if you didn't have to close it. :p

Comment: For each call to `getInstance()` you need to have a call to `close()`. If you don't close realms, you will run into out of memoery exceptions

Comment: *Did you try Realm's Transaction blocks? You don't need to rely on opening and closing if you use that.* That's incorrect. Transaction blocks only handle `begin()` and `commit()` of a transaction, you cannot perform a transaction without a realm instance

Comment: You definitely need to control de opening a closing of instances. This is not the main problem, nevertheless, since you can open/close the Realm inside every DBUtils method. The problem is that you will have to _copy_ all objects.. so they won't be automatically updated and they will be heavier in terms of performance.

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't really answer the question. As pointed out by @josemigallas, adding a `DbUtils` wrapper defies the whole point of using `Realm` in the first place.

Comment: @verybadalloc Have mentioned that already as an `update` to the answer! Please don't down vote just for sake of it!

Answer (score 4):

With the latest Google I/O 2017 announcement for `Android Architectural Components`, the proper way to abstract Realm in Android apps is:

1.) Realm instance lifecycle is managed by `ViewModel` class, and it is closed in `onCleared()` method

2.) RealmResults is a `MutableLiveData<List<T>>`, so you can create a `RealmLiveData<T>` class which wraps a `RealmResults<T>`.

Therefore, you can create a view model like this:

```
// based on  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/178fe541643adb122d2a8925cf61a21950a4611c/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/viewmodel/ProductListViewModel.java
public class ProductListViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<List<ProductEntity>> observableProducts = new MutableLiveData<>();

    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<ProductEntity> results;
    RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<ProductEntity>> realmChangeListener = (results) -> {
        if(results.isLoaded() && results.isValid()) { // you probably don't need this, just making sure.
            observableProducts.setValue(results);
        }
    };

    public ProductListViewModel() {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();             
        results = realm.where(ProductEntity.class).findAllSortedAsync("id"); 
          // could use a Realm DAO class here
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);

        observableProducts.setValue(null); // if using async query API, the change listener will set the loaded results.
    }

    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
        return observableProducts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }
}
```

or you can separate them into a realm viewmodel and a realm livedata based on [this article](https://news.realm.io/news/android-architecture-components-and-realm/):

```
public class LiveRealmData<T extends RealmModel> extends LiveData<RealmResults<T>> {

    private RealmResults<T> results;
    private final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener = 
        new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<T> results) { setValue(results);}
    };

    public LiveRealmData(RealmResults<T> realmResults) {
        results = realmResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        results.addChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        results.removeChangeListener(listener);
    }
}

public class CustomResultViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private Realm mDb;
    private LiveData<String> mLoansResult;

    public CustomResultViewModel() {
        mDb = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        mLoansResult = RealmUtils.loanDao(mDb).getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getLoansResult() {
        return mLoansResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        mDb.close();
        super.onCleared();
    }
}
```

Either way, you've wrapped Realm's auto-updating and lazy-loaded result set into a LiveData and ViewModel, separate from the fragments/adapters:

```
// based on https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/178fe541643adb122d2a8925cf61a21950a4611c/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ProductListFragment.java
public class ProductListFragment extends LifecycleFragment {
    private ProductAdapter productAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mProductClickCallback);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final ProductListViewModel viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductListViewModel.class); // <-- !

        subscribeUi(viewModel);
    }

    private void subscribeUi(ProductListViewModel viewModel) {
        // Update the list when the data changes
        viewModel.getProducts().observe(this, (myProducts) -> {
            if (myProducts == null) {
                // ...
            } else {
                productAdapter.setProductList(myProducts);
                //...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

But if you are **not** using Android Architectural Components, even then what one needs to keep in mind is that:

> RealmResults is a list of proxy objects that mutates in place, and it has change listeners.

So what you need is either wrapping it as Flowable with LATEST backpressure, akin to

```
private io.reactivex.Flowable<RealmResults<T>> realmResults() {
    return io.reactivex.Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<RealmResults<T>>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<RealmResults<T>> emitter)
                throws Exception {
            Realm observableRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            RealmResults<T> results = realm.where(clazz)./*...*/.findAllSortedAsync("field", Sort.ASCENDING);
            final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener = _results -> {
                if(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                    emitter.onNext(_results);
                }
            };
            emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromRunnable(() -> {
                observableRealm.removeChangeListener(listener);
                observableRealm.close();
            }));
            observableRealm.addChangeListener(listener);
            emitter.onNext(observableRealm);
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST).subscribeOn(scheduler).unsubscribeOn(scheduler);
```

Or creating your own `MutableLiveList` interface.

```
public interface MutableLiveList<T> extends List<T> { 
     public interface ChangeListener {
         void onChange(MutableLiveList<T> list);
     }

     void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
     void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation, but do you have a TL;DR between the above article you linked and this one:
https://hackernoon.com/musing-on-architectural-components-and-realm-and-room-and-a-look-at-reactive-clean-architecture-880c8df55abf

Comment: @Phileo99 this is the tldr

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Hey, we had talked last week about realm abstractions. I finished mine up and wired it up to a DAO/view model. Could you give this a glance and let me know your thoughts? I want to make sure I'm not making some critical error. Thanks! https://gist.github.com/danielchristopher1/0fa253dcec60ecd77b316543efe6dc73

Comment: @DanielChristopher I can't help but feel like `fun addChangeListener(changeListener: ChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>` should receive `ChangeListener<Results<T>>`

Answer (score 1):

Providing a different opinion, since I down-voted the other answer. I would like to first discuss your objective

> in case of need, I can switch back to a standard SQLite based DB without rewriting most of the app

Realm is not equivalent to a standard SQLite-based DB. What you are looking for in that case is something like [StorIO](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/blob/master/docs/StorIOSQLite.md). Realm is designed in such a way that you have to use `RealmObject` as base for your models. If you just want to retrieve data from a table, Realm is not for you.

Now, after the Parse debacle, the need for abstracting an third-party library became apparent. So, if that's your motivation, then you really have to wrap every single thing you use from Realm. Something like this:

```
public class Db {

  public class Query<M extends RealmObject> {

    private final RealmQuery<M> realmQuery;

    Query(Db db, Class<M> clazz) {
        this.realmQuery = RealmQuery.createQuery(db.realmInstance, clazz);
    }

    public Query<M> equalTo(String field, Integer value) {
        realmQuery.equalTo(field, value);
        return this;
    }

    public Results<M> findAll() {
        return new Results<>(realmQuery.findAll());
    }

    public M findFirst() {
        return realmQuery.findFirst();
    }
  }

  public class Results<M extends RealmObject> extends AbstractList<M> {

    private final RealmResults<M> results;

    Results(RealmResults<M> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public void removeLast() {
        results.removeLast();
    }

    @Override
    public M get(int i) {
        return results.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return results.size();
    }
  }

  public interface Transaction {
    void execute();

    abstract class Callback {
        public abstract void onSuccess();

        public void onError(Throwable error) {
        }
    }
  }

  private Realm realmInstance;

  Db() {
    realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
  }

  public void executeTransaction(@NonNull Db.Transaction dbTransaction) {
    realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> dbTransaction.execute());
  }

  public void close() {
    realmInstance.close();
  }
}
```

At this point, you just define whichever operations you are using in your app on the `Db` class. And, if you are like me, you are probably not using all of them, so you should be fine.

Is this pretty? No. Is it necessary? Depends on what you want to achieve.

**Edit**: for bonus point, have `Db` implement `AutoCloseable`:

```
try(Db db = new Db()) {
     db.executeTransaction(() -> /*...*/);
}
```

Comment: `Realm is not equivalent to a standard SQLite-based DB.` agreed. It is more than an SQLite database, and thinking of it as "just an SQLite db" means you'll make a faulty abstraction for it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce would you consider an abstraction like this acceptable? I have implemented something like this myself.

Comment: This is actually a pretty reasonable abstraction (wrapping all Realm APIs under an interface), I've been lazy to do it myself but it is a valid option. You just need to make sure you do the `try(Db db = new Db())` thing on their own respective threads, so the Realm lifecycle management cannot be ditched. With the latest Google I/O 2017 *Architecture Components*, another alternative is that you can hide Realm in Android's own reactive abstractions.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce awesome, thank you for clarifying that. Can you check out the abstraction I have developed? Here's a gist. https://gist.github.com/danielchristopher1/befc5a55d8f3070d032b8dcd55bf55e5

Comment: @DanielChristopher it depends on what `realmManager.getRealm()` does, and when the "managed" instance inside it is closed.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have not been sure when to close the realm instance managed by RealmManagerService. The instance of RealmManagerService is managed by my Application's Dagger component which has a lifetime equal to the full application lifetime. Would it be appropriate to close the realm instance at the end of my application ? I am skeptical of reopening and closing for every transaction and think it may be better to keep it open for faster access.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm only iffy about this because I tried to do something [very similar a while ago](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/commit/a511e0fedb8c4373f6edd84f9985dadb12336dda), and it just didn't work. I'm not sure why. Personally I tend to open/close for background thread `run()` method, and on UI thread I count the number of open activities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145556/discussion-between-daniel-christopher-and-epicpandaforce).