# Manage Realm between Services and Application

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, realm

I'm working on an Android application that receives some BLE data in a service, then store them to a `Realm` Database and obviously show on `Activities` and `Fragments`.
I've setup a `Singleton` class called `RealmManager` that use a single `Realm` instance (with getDefaultInstance) to execute transaction and queries.
If i call `RealmManager` methods to store new data to `Realm`, an exception will be fired because I'm using Realm on a different Thread. In this example, I cannot call `RealmManager.sharedInstance().userWithEmail("pippo")` from service and from activities:

```
public class RealmManager {

     private static Realm realmDB;
     private static RealmManager ourInstance;

     public RealmManager(){
       realmDB = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     }

     public static RealmManager sharedInstance(){
        if(ourInstance == null)
           ourInstance = new RealmManager();
     }

    public User userWithEmail(String email){
        User user = realmDB.where(User.class).equalTo(USER_EMAIL, email).findFirst();
        return user;
    }
}
```

If I instantiate a new `Realm` instance on every method and then call the `Realm.close` at the end, I cannot use realm result across application because `Realm` instance is already closed.
In this example, i cannot use `user` in the caller because instance is already closed:

```
public ArrayList<Patient> getPatientsForLoggedUser() {
       final Realm realmDB = 
       Realm.getInstance(RealmManager.getDefaultInstance();
       try {
           ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>(realmDB.where(Patient.class).equalTo("user.email", loggedUser().getEmail()).findAllSorted("firstName", Sort.ASCENDING));
           return patients;
       } finally {
           if(realmDB != null)
               realmDB.close();
       }
    }
```

How to have a RealmManager class to save and retrieve all the application's DB data from Application and service?

Comment: `ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>(realmDB.where(Patient.class).equalTo("user.email", loggedUser().getEmail()).findAllSorted("firstName", Sort.ASCENDING));` that's like the worst possible thing you can do. Either copy from the Realm (which you generally shouldn't) or return `RealmResults`, but don't return an arrayList of proxies because that's bad.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you for the feedback, i'll refactor my methods. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a singleton Realm like that.

Normally you'd need `ThreadLocal<Realm>` for this, but Realm already manages this internally using the so-called [`RealmCache`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmCache.java), which looks kinda like this:

```
private static class RefAndCount {
    // The global Realm instance in this thread.
    private final ThreadLocal<BaseRealm> localRealm = new ThreadLocal<>();

    // How many local references to this Realm instance in this thread.
    private final ThreadLocal<Integer> localCount = new ThreadLocal<>();

    // How many threads have instances refer to this configuration.
    private int globalCount = 0;
}

private synchronized <E extends BaseRealm> E doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmConfiguration configuration) {
    RefAndCount refAndCount = refAndCountMap.get(RealmCacheType.valueOf(Realm.class));

    if (refAndCount.localRealm.get() == null) {
        // Creates a new local Realm instance
        BaseRealm realm = Realm.createInstance(this);
        refAndCount.localRealm.set(realm);
        refAndCount.localCount.set(0);

        refAndCount.globalCount++;
    }

    Integer refCount = refAndCount.localCount.get();
    refAndCount.localCount.set(refCount + 1);

    //noinspection unchecked
    return (E) refAndCount.localRealm.get();
}


synchronized void release(BaseRealm realm) {
    String canonicalPath = realm.getPath();
    RefAndCount refAndCount = refAndCountMap.get(RealmCacheType.valueOf(Realm.class));
    Integer refCount = refAndCount.localCount.get();
    if (refCount == null) {
        refCount = 0;
    }

    if (refCount <= 0) {
        RealmLog.warn("%s has been closed already. refCount is %s", canonicalPath, refCount);
        return;
    }

    refCount -= 1;

    if (refCount == 0) {
        refAndCount.localCount.set(null);
        refAndCount.localRealm.set(null);

        refAndCount.globalCount--;
        if (refAndCount.globalCount < 0) {
            // Should never happen.
            throw new IllegalStateException("Global reference counter of Realm" + canonicalPath + " got corrupted.");
        }

        realm.doClose();

        if (getTotalGlobalRefCount() == 0) {
            configuration = null;
        }
    } else {
        refAndCount.localCount.set(refCount);
    }
}
```

With that in mind, what we've learned is:

1.) `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` **increases local count**, and opens a new global thread-local Realm instance 
if `localCount 0 -> 1`

2.) `realm.close()` decreases the local count

3.) if `localCount 1 -> 0`, then global thread-local Realm instance is released

4.) all of these methods are `synchronized` in implementation

---

And with that in mind, you probably shouldn't create a global Realm instance for all threads. Mostly because you'd be creating a thread-local cache on top of an already existing thread-local cache, and it gets tricky. Although you can check [this question as an example from daniel christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473611/proper-way-to-abstract-realm-in-android-apps) (the [gist](https://gist.github.com/danielchristopher1/befc5a55d8f3070d032b8dcd55bf55e5)).

---

Generally, you should provide local Realm instance and close those.

The [documentation describes the best practices for managing Realm instance lifecycle](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances), although personally I prefer to keep only 1 Realm instance per thread.

Comment: With that in mind, can I keep all my Realm interaction in a static class like my RealmManager, passing a Realm instance in every call and use It instead of keeping only one in the singleton?

Comment: `passing a Realm instance in every call and use It instead of keeping only one in the singleton` yes, in fact, I recommend it. That's how I created my [DAO classes for Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560557/2413303)

Comment: Another option is to create the DAO class with the Realm of the given thread as a parameter as you can see in [Realm's article](https://news.realm.io/news/android-architecture-components-and-realm/) that came out yesterday about Architecture Components (while in [my article you can see that I'm passing Realm in as method argument](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/musing-on-architectural-components-and-realm-and-room-and-a-look-at-reactive-clean-architecture-880c8df55abf))

Comment: @fustalol I've just received a new alternative at https://gist.github.com/danielchristopher1/befc5a55d8f3070d032b8dcd55bf55e5 in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473611/proper-way-to-abstract-realm-in-android-apps) and it seems to be valid, as long as you're responsible about where to call `open`, `get` and `close`.

Comment: I've setup all my Realm methods with a Realm instance. I've setup a Realm instance on Application class and one in the service class. Still "Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created." error.

Comment: I'd have to see your code and where the exception happens to answer you "why"

Comment: I need to know the stack trace and the exact location in code where you get the exception.